# Is it possible to generate an input file for band structure calculations for multiple KPaths at once?

Tags: quantum-espresso, band-structure, bandgap

I need to generate an input file for band structure calculation along the following k path. how do I input the k path in the "bands.in" file? here, i need to calculate the band gap along all of the mentioned kpaths.
[image]

```
&control
  calculation = 'bands',
  restart_mode = 'from_scratch',
  prefix = 'bands2',
  outdir = './tmp/'
  pseudo_dir = '/home/psuedo_sr'
  verbosity = 'high'
/

&system
    ibrav = 5,
    celldm(1) = 10.52826895, ! in bohr units
    celldm(4) = 0.5696, 
    nat = 10, ntyp = 3,
    ecutwfc = 50,
    ecutrho = 400.0,
    nbnd = 100,
    nspin=2,
    starting_magnetization(1) =   3
    starting_magnetization(2) =   0.5
    starting_magnetization(3) =   0.1
/

&electrons
    conv_thr = 1.0e-10
    electron_maxstep = 500
    mixing_beta = 0.3d0
/

ATOMIC_SPECIES
     Fe 55.845 Fe.pbe-spn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
     Ti 47.867 Ti.pbe-spn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
     O  15.999 O.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF

ATOMIC_POSITIONS (crystal)
Ti     0.145414993         0.145414710         0.145414993
Ti     0.854586005         0.854584396         0.854586005
Fe     0.357185096         0.357184410         0.357185096
Fe     0.642815828         0.642814636         0.642815828
O     0.562447965         0.953017414         0.220108926
O     0.953018606         0.220107913         0.562447786
O     0.220108837         0.562446773         0.953018665
O     0.437552989         0.046981703         0.779892027
O     0.046982408         0.779891193         0.437553167
O     0.779892147         0.437552273         0.046982329

K_POINTS {crystal_b}
13
   0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000     20 !GAMMA
   0.5000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000     20 !L
   0.7662337662     0.2337662338     0.5000000000     20 !B1
   0.5000000000    -0.2337662338     0.2337662338     20 !B
   0.0000000000    -0.5000000000     0.0000000000     20 !Z
   0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000     20 !GAMMA
   0.7662337662     0.3666666667     0.3666666667     20 !X
   0.6333333333     0.0000000000     0.3666666667     20 !Q
   0.5000000000     0.0000000000     0.5000000000     20 !F
   0.3666666667    -0.2337662338     0.3666666667     20 !P1
   0.0000000000    -0.5000000000     0.0000000000     20 !Z
   0.5000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000     20 !L
   0.3666666667    -0.3666666667     0.0000000000     20 !P 
           
HUBBARD (atomic)
  U Fe-3d 5.3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an input file for band calculation](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/11608/how-to-create-an-input-file-for-band-calculation)

Comment: @Anyon Thanks for the information. Do u have any idea about giving two or more K-paths at once, is that correct?

Comment: @Prasad Did you get the answer for your question with the link provided by Anyon?

Comment: @JaafarMehrez not yet got any clear answer.

Comment: I am not a QE user, but from the input file you have provided there is a clear example of defining K_POINTS, which in general corresponds to the high symmetrical path that goes through those special points in the first BZ. When you calculate the band structure then you are doing the calculation along one KPATH, and if you are interested in studying the bandstructure along other KPATHs then you will need to do seperate calculations. is that clear to you? I really can't understand what you exactly need in your question, let me know if you need further assistance. Regards~

Comment: @JaafarMehrez Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @JaafarMehrez is quite right: you'll need to run separate calculations. Just run the `pw.x` executable in `bands` mode with different `K_POINTS` corresponding to your paths, then process them (with different `filband` names!) with `bands.x`. I am not sure how to do it in parallel instead of sequentially, though.